# How to generate project wide UML class diagram in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm in a process of reverse-engineering a legacy code. Is there any way that I could generate a project wide UML class diagram in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 ? (Not individual class diagram for each class separately)

Answer (score 2):

In visual studio 2015 I could generate the full class diagram by following the below steps.

1. Right click on the solution in Solution Explorer window.
2. Go to "View"
3. Select "View Class Diagram"

[image]

Then the class diagram is generated.
You can change its properties too according to your preference